# Eclipse CVS Project inside Remote SSH Project

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I have Eclipse PHP Helios and I've setup successfully a new SSH connection to my remote server. One of the directories has Drupal installed and this directory is set up as Remote project. I have the right permissions and everything works perfectly. Now I am trying to import a new project from CVS and check it out into the existing remote project. Unfortunately I get the following error:

`Errors saving CVS synchronization information to disk. Please fix the problems listed below and then update the affected resources from the CVS repository.
Missing element for : '': rse://192.168.1.253/srv/apachesolr2/CVS/Entries
Missing element for : '': rse://192.168.1.253/srv/apachesolr2/CVS/Entries
Missing element for : ''`

What can I do to be able to import the cvs project into the remote location?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Eclipse CVS supports remote locations. You can try to work with a work copy on your local disk and then synchronize it with remote using RSE sync features.

Comment: It would've been perfect if it did. I could however use the command line in the terminal for all the cvs commands on the remote server, but Eclipse's client would be nicer...